# Python, reading RDF files, scraping Gutenberg books

Tags: python-3.x, rdf

I am aware that Gutenberg (a company providing public domain books) does not allow automatic access of their website, they do however provide them in a 'machine readable format' just for that purpose, specifically RDF. I, being new, have never heard of this format, and googling hasn't helped much. I have acquired the rdflib module that I quite frankly have no idea what to do with.

What I am trying to do is extract the text which I assume is legally accessible through the RDF files that I downloaded. In the rdf file there is, among others, this line:

```
<dcterms:hasFormat rdf:resource="http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.txt.utf-8"/>
```

It leads to the Gutenberg page with the text file of the book, from where I assume the program can get the text, though I'm not sure since I don't see the distinction between directly scraping their site, and scraping it through the RDF file.

So, if the text is at all accessible programmatically, how would I do it?

Comment: Project Gutenberg provide their catalog in RDF not the actual book text so this won't solve your problem

Comment: @RobV I think that user's point was that the triple `<something> dcterms:hasFormat <http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/100.txt.utf-8>` provides a URL for the text.  I agree, though, that if automated access is forbidden, just having a URL doesn't help, because accessing it would still be an automatic access.

Comment: What searches on Google didn't help much?  The first few hits from a [Google search for rdf](https://www.google.com/search?q=rdf) are all about what RDF is, how it's used, what it looks like, etc.

Comment: It was nothing that seemed like it would be what I wanted, which was evidently because it isn't meant for what I need, therefore I assumed I missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't find full text in the [RDF catalog from from Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aFeeds#Current_RDF_Format). It does contain URLs for the text in several formats, though. Once you've downloaded the [catalog zip file](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/feeds/rdf-files.tar.zip) and unzipped it, here's how to get HTML book URL from a particular RDF file.

```
filename = 'cache/epub/78/pg78.rdf'
from lxml import etree
rdf = open(filename).read()
tree = etree.fromstring(rdf)
resource_tag = '{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}resource'
hasFormat_tag = './/{http://purl.org/dc/terms/}hasFormat'
resources = [el.attrib[resource_tag] for el in tree.findall(hasFormat_tag)]
urls = [url for url in resources if url.endswith('htm')]
// urls[0] is 'http://www.gutenberg.org/files/78/78-h/78-h.htm'
```

Once you have the URL of the HTML version of the book you want, here's how to grab the text.

```
import requests
from lxml import etree
response = requests.get(urls[0])
html = etree.HTML(response.text)
text = '\n'.join([el.text for el in html.findall('.//p')])
```

`text` now contains the full text of [Tarzan](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/78/78-h/78-h.htm), minus the Project Gutenberg metadata, table of contents, and chapter headings.

```
>>> text[:100]
u'\r\nI had this story from one who had no business to tell it to me, or to\r\nany other.  I may credit th'
```

Note that there are inconsistencies between books on Gutenberg so your results may vary.